# Use of Proxies in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, proxy

I'm a little confused after reading some of Sencha's doc's.

From what I've read, ExtJS places proxies between models/stores and client/server. Now, say I have a store that needs to load data that could be located in a local cache, or HTML5-LocalStorage, and if not needs to `GET` from a server. Do I configure a *single* proxy that manages this (which, in my opinion is a nice, clean, separation of concerns), or *separate* proxies per source.

Any clarification is apprecaited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to probably do this is to not auto-load the store. Do the logic seperate from the proxy. Check whether the data is in local cache or HTML 5 Storage. If it is, load that data using `loadData`. If it is neither of those, tell the store to load itself, therefore, using the proxy set up on the store. This means you will only have 1 Store and 1 Proxy.

```
if (dataIsInLocalCache) {
    store.loadData(dataFromLocalCache);
} else if (dataisInHTML5Storage) {
    store.loadData(dataFromHTMLStorage);
} else {
    store.load();
}
```

Comment: Jeff, thanks for the response! Looks like a good idea. From a design pov, where should this logic reside? Between the controller and store?

Comment: That's where I would put it.